# Does Win7 support scheduling system image backups?

Tags: windows-7, backup, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to schedule/automate system image backups in Windows 7 Pro? Or do I have to do it manually every time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/11340-add-system-image-backup-task-scheduler.html

> In Task Scheduler, click Create Task. Click the Actions tab. Click the New button.
>
> Leave Action on "Start a Program." In the "Program/script" field, type in WBADMIN. Then under "add arguments," type in:
>
> START BACKUP -backupTarget:X: -include:c:
>
> where "X" is the drive letter of your backup drive, and "c" is your primary hard drive.
>
> Set the triggers, settings, and conditions to whatever you like.
>
> Image Backup does an incremental "ghost" of your HD, adding any changes since your last Image Backup, and keeping all previous backups available as well.

.

Answer (score 5):

[This](http://www.sevenforums.com/general-discussion/11340-add-system-image-backup-task-scheduler.html) post mentions that you don't need to use task scheduler to schedule a system image backup. Just enable scheduled backups, and check the 'system image' box when you configure it.

> you do not need to use scheduled tasks. Go to back up and restore -
>   change settings-next-let me choose. You have the option to include
>   system image on the schedule that you have chosen. I see now that the
>   insturctions were given by the prior poster. In any case, enjoy.

I've been using this approach to push an image backup to a network drive, and it's working fine so far. It's also nice setting it up this way (as opposed to a scheduled task and command) b/c there's an informative backup status screen that comes with the windows backup utility, that gives you feedback on last successful backup, next backup, size of image, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I wish to include this site which explains more about WBAdmin and the start backup command.
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742083.aspx

What I found useful is that the -include option can take a comma-delimited set of drives. So if you have your OS C: drive and, say, a Storage D: drive that you want imaged, use:

```
START BACKUP -backupTarget:X: -include:C:,D:
```

Comment: You might want to use something like `WBADMIN START BACKUP -backupTarget:B: -include:d:,e: -allCritical`. Adding `-allCritical` will include all system disks (e.g. C: but also folder-dirves connected to C:).