# How do I make a backup of Windows 8?

Tags: backup, windows-8, windows-backup

Coming from MacOS X (with Time Machine) back to Windows 8, I'm wondering how I can make good (useful) backups of Windows 8 and my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The windows 8 equivalent is File History, below is a very good article on what it is and how to set it up:

[Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/b8/protecting-user-files-with-file-history)

> File History is a backup application that continuously protects your
> personal files stored in Libraries, Desktop, Favorites, and Contacts
> folders. It periodically (by default every hour) scans the file system
> for changes and copies changed files to another location. Every time
> any of your personal files has changed, its copy will be stored on a
> dedicated, external storage device selected by you. Over time, File
> History builds a complete history of changes made to any personal
> file.
>
> It’s a feature introduced in Windows 8 that offers a new way to
> protect files for consumers. It supersedes the existing Windows Backup
> and Restore features of Windows 7.

---

> FAQ
>
> **What happens when you upgrade to Windows 8 from Windows 7?**
> If Windows
> 7 Backup was active, i.e. it was scheduled and the schedule was
> active, then it will continue running as scheduled after the upgrade.
> File History will be disabled by default and users will not be able to
> turn it on as long as the Windows 7 Backup schedule is active. To turn
> it you will have to first disable the Windows 7 Backup schedule.
>
> **Can Windows 7 users use File History?**
> Windows 7 users cannot use File
> History. However, they can restore files from a drive used by File
> History by browsing the volume in the Windows Explorer and selecting a
> specific file. Files on the File History drive are stored in the same
> relative location, and use the same name. The specific version can be
> identified by the time stamp appended to the file name.
>
> **Does File History protect the operating system and applications?**
> File
> History only protects user libraries, desktop, favorites and contacts.
> Other files, such as operating system files, applications, and
> settings, are not backed up.
>
> **Can File History be used with cloud storage?**
> No. File History is
> designed specifically for consumers and does not support cloud storage
> in this release. Windows 8 Server offers a backup feature that can
> back up files to a cloud. This feature is available on the Server
> version of Windows and is designed for small and medium businesses.
>
> **Can File History be used by enterprise customers?**
> Yes. However,
> enterprise customers should be aware that File History may not comply
> with their company security, access, and retention policies. For that
> reason, we offer a group policy setting that allows enterprise
> administrators to disable the feature for an entire organization.
>
> **Will File History protect files stored on a file share?**
> No. File
> History only protects file stored on a local drive.
>
> If you use offline folders and folder redirection, your folders (like
> My Documents or My Pictures) are redirected to a network share and
> will not be protected. If you add a network location to any of your
> libraries, this location will not be protected.

Comment: The Windows 8 "File history" is derived directly from the "Shadow copies" function in Windows Server

Answer (score 4):

Windows 8's backup system differs from Windows 7's one. Windows 8 has File History that stores ca copy of your data. You can read more about it in HowToGeek's article [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/123713/how-windows-8s-backup-system-differs-from-windows-7s/).

Be aware that Windows 8 only supports the backup of userdata.

> There’s been a major philosophical change in Windows 8. You can no
> longer create full system images, nor can you back up everything on
> your hard drive. Instead, you can only back up files in your
> libraries, files on your desktop, your contacts, and your browser
> favorites.

You can still use the old system image backup tool of Windows and schedule disk images backup, instructions [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/4241/how-to-create-a-system-image-in-windows-7/).

To schedule backups follow instructions as [per this post](https://superuser.com/questions/244576/does-win7-support-scheduling-system-image-backups).

> In Task Scheduler, click Create Task. Click the Actions tab. Click the New button.
>
> Leave Action on "Start a Program." In the "Program/script" field, type in WBADMIN. Then under "add arguments," type in:
>
> START BACKUP -backupTarget:X: -include:c:
>
> where "X" is the drive letter of your backup drive, and "c" is your primary hard drive.
>
> Set the triggers, settings, and conditions to whatever you like.
>
> Image Backup does an incremental "ghost" of your HD, adding any changes since your last Image Backup, and keeping all previous backups available as well.

Answer (score 0):

Personally I use [CrashPlan](http://www.crashplan.com) for all my personal data. Everything up to their cloud storage and a subset to an external drive for faster recovery (would have everything both places if the drive was big enough :)

In addition it's a good idea to regularly create an image of your system drive like [HackToHell suggests](https://superuser.com/a/492014/62) for those cases where you do something stupid, create a complete mess of your OS and really wish you could take a fairly quick step back in time :p Haven't set this up myself yet in Windows 8, but had this as a nightly scheduled task in Windows 7. Saved me from having to reinstall *everything* a couple of times...